# How to set a select list's options with jQuery 3.3.1

Tags: jquery, html-select

I've tried most of the answers to previous questions here, but I can't get jQuery to set an option in a select list as selected.  I do get and iterate each option's text. Using jQuery 3.3.1.

HTML:

```
<select id="ddlRole" class="ddlRole" style="width:810px" multiple  size="6">
   <option value="-1">--DeSelect--</option>
   <option value="1">Administrator</option>
   <option value="2">Manager</option>
   <option value="3">User</option>
</select>
```

Code:

```
$('#ddlrole option').each(function ()                               
{
    //alert(" option text =" + this.text);
    for (i = 1; i < splitdata.length; i++)
    {
        if (splitdata[i] == $(this).text())
        {
            //this.prop("selected",true);
            //$(this).prop('selected', true);                                       $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            alert("Searched text is found");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: $("option").attr("selected"); in your iteration .. tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no options specified in your select Tag

```
    <select id="ddlRole" class="ddlRole" style="width:810px" multiple  size="6"></select>
```

More over what is the splitdata variable? it is undefined

**EDIT:**

Try This:

```
splitdata = ["Administrator","Manager","User"]

$('#ddlRole option').each(function ()                               
{
        console.log(" option text =");
        for (i = 0; i < splitdata.length; i++)
        {
            if (splitdata[i] == $(this).text())
            { 
             $(this).attr("selected", "selected");
            }
        }
});
```

Comment: the splitdata variable is an array of names which are matches on the option's text. and I've updated the question with the options

Comment: could you provide a working js fiddle with your problem? will help in understanding the scenario

Comment: I've never tried a js fiddle, still new to all this, thanks though. You can replace splitdata[I]  with 'Administrator'

Comment: i Have updated the answer check this out.. Your Id was mismatching from the HTML and Jquery

Answer (score 0):

If your dropdown's values are also same, why not try passing the array to the `val()` method? Because it will do the job for you!

HTML:

```
<select id="ddlRole" class="ddlRole" style="width:810px" multiple  size="6">
  <option value="A">A</option>
  <option value="B">B</option>
  <option value="C">C</option>
  <option value="D">D</option>
  <option value="E">E</option>
  <option value="F">F</option>
  <option value="G">G</option>
</select>
```

jQuery:

```
var splitdata = ['B', 'C', 'E'];
$('#ddlRole').val(splitdata);
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/u4znpasy/)

Apart from that, I would like to point out a couple of things:

1. Your dropdown element's ID name is `ddlRole`, whereas in the jQuery code, you are using `#ddlrole`.
2. Your `FOR` loop starts from `1`. But in an array, the first element starts from `0`th index.

Comment: Thanks, re ddlR.. vs ddlr   and the reason I start from 1 is the 0th element is '-- DeSelect --' which I don't want to match on.

Comment: That's why we requests everyone to provide detailed info when posting a question. Otherwise we would keep guessing! You didn't provided the options of that dropdown initially. And only now I noticed that you have edited your question and included it. Anyway, glad to know your issue is resolved!